# Pytorch 1.8 hangs by chance when calling loss.backward()

Tags: pytorch

When I was training an LSTM on `pytorch` the training process hangs by chance and **cannot be terminated by Crlt+C**. Then I used `faulthandler` to locate the problem. The training parameters, environment and `faulthandler` traceback output are listed below. It seems to be some problem with the C++ backend or the CUDA or even my graphic card I do not know.

Trace output batch_size = 64/32/16, num_workers = 2, CUDA 11.1, pytorch 1.8.0, cuDNN 8.0.5/8.0.1:

> Thread 0x000036e8 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 302 in wait
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py",
> line 227 in _feed   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in
> _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00004644 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 302 in wait
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py",
> line 227 in _feed   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in
> _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00000efc (most recent call first):
>
> Thread 0x00000138 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 558 in
> wait   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm_monitor.py",
> line 59 in run   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in
> _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00001644 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\queue.py", line 179 in get
> File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py",
> line 232 in run   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in
> _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x0000443c (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd_*init*_.py",
> line 145 in backward   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py",
> line 245 in backward   File "train.py", line 129 in main   File
> "train.py", line 246 in
>
> batch_size = 64, num_workers = 0,  CUDA 11.1, pytorch 1.8.0, cuDNN
> 8.0.5 Thread 0x00003650 (most recent call first):
>
> Thread 0x000043b4 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 558 in wait   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm_monitor.py", line 59
> in run   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x000017c4 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 306 in wait   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\queue.py", line 179 in get   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py",
> line 232 in run   File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py",
> line 932 in _bootstrap_inner   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00001458 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd_*init*_.py",
> line 145 in backward   File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 245
> in backward   File "train.py", line 129 in main   File "train.py",
> line 246 in

When num_workers=0 the output is the same except for lacking two threads below that I think belong to the dataloader.

> Thread 0x000036e8 (most recent call first): File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 302 in wait
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py",
> line 227 in _feed File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in
> _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00004644 (most recent call first): File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 302 in wait
> File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py",
> line 227 in _feed File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run File
> "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932 in
> _bootstrap_inner File "C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in
> _bootstrap

The resource usage is also moderate, with around 20% CPU usage, 16/32GB memory, and 3.8/8GB graphics memory usage. The GPU usage is low when training RNNs. The script was run on Windows 10. The graphic card I use is RTX 3070. The driver version for my graphics card is 461.09.

#### More Information

When I started debugging code I was using the unmatching versions of CUDA 11.2 with pytorch 1.7.1 and cudnn 8.1.0. At that time I came into CUDA exceptions from time to time, with outputs like kernel launch failed or failed to synchronization, and things just hang without error after I changed my CUDA version.

Comment: I just had the same issue when training an LSTM model using Flair NLP [ https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_9_TRAINING_LM_EMBEDDINGS.md ].

The interesting part is that finetuning a model using the exact same code does not cause this issue, so I'm expecting the issue only happens in a particular case that is unlikely to happen when the model is already stable.

I'm using CUDA on WSL, with an RTX 3090 (so can't test on v1.7).

Comment: @FremyCompany Thank you. I am using RTX 3070 and I added the information to my question.